# Is the clique decision problem in co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, clique, co-np

Is the *clique decision* problem in *co-NP*?

**Definitions**:

"In the *clique decision problem*, the input is an undirected graph and a number k, and the output is a Boolean value: true if the graph contains a k-clique, and false otherwise." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)

"A decision problem is in *co-NP* precisely if only no-instances have a polynomial-length "certificate" and there is a polynomial-time algorithm that can be used to verify any purported certificate." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP)

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You've quoted the definition.  So, can you come up with a certificate and a verifier algorithm?  What approaches have you tried?  What difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: A verifier for the clique decision problem's membership in NP is trivial: the certificate is a k-clique. I ask about co-NP, though. Graph colorings appear to be good certificates for the converse of the clique decision problem, but are actually not precise enough. There are graphs with different clique and chromatic numbers. I suspect that the answer to my question is not known and an authoritative source saying as much would be an acceptable "solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not known, but believed to be unlikely.  The Clique problem is NP-complete.  If a NP-complete problem was in co-NP, then we would have NP = co-NP.  It is an open problem whether NP = co-NP, but most complexity theorists expect that NP != co-NP -- which would imply that Clique is not in co-NP.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP#Relationship_to_other_classes, [If $NP \neq co-NP$ then no $NP-complete$ problem can be in $co-NP$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76888/755)